# TFS build run custom code

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-reports

I am looking at possible solution for generating the report showing code analysis warnings chart (ex: design guidelines count on y-axis and days on x-axis)

I see TFS build logs code analysis warnings to TFS database but it is only total count.

I am thinking about the below approach 
Write a custom code to parse the code analysis xml and write the required info to database (Design violations count, naming conventions count etc). Create a report to pull the data and show the violations chart. Make the TFS build execute the custom code as part of the build.
Bit of googling points to custom warehouse adapter.

Is this feasible approach or anything better exists.